# Surround string with another string

Tags: java

I there any utils method in Java that would enable me to surround a string with another string? Something like:

```
surround("hello","%");
```

which would return `"%hello%"`

I need just one method so the code would be nicer then adding prefix and suffix. Also I don't want to have a custom utils class if it's not necessary.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a method, but it's a single line implementation, so hardly difficult to write yourself...

Comment: I agree, but still it is an implementation, which adds my custom code to the system. I need it on more places, so I need some util class, which should be tested, has a possibility for error etc.. So I'm looking for an existing solution.

Comment: It's a single line. It's easy to test. As I've said, I don't think such a method exists in Java (it's not that common a thing to want to do.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String.format can be used for this purpose:

`String s = String.format("%%%s%%", "hello");`

Comment: Thanks for an idea, however the correct escaping sequence is "%%%s%%"

Comment: yeah sure ;) sorry for that, I'm more C/C++ guy

Answer (score 6):

No but you can always create a method to do this:

```
public String surround(String str, String surroundingStr) {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(surroundingStr).append(str).append(surroundingStr);

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

You have another method of doing it but **Do not do this if you want better performance:-**

```
public String surround(String str, String surroundingStr){

    return surroundingStr + str + surroundingStr;
}
```

## Why not use the second method?

As we all know, Strings in Java are immutable. When you concatinate strings thrice, it creates two new string objects apart from your original strings `str` and `surroundingStr`. And so a total of 4 string objects are created:

```
1. str
2. surroundingStr  
3. surroundingStr + str
4. (surroundingStr + str) + surroundingStr
```

And creating of objects do take time. So for long run, the second method will downgrade your performance in terms of space and time. So it's your choice what method is to be used.

## Though this is not the case after java 1.4

as concatinating strings with `+` operator uses `StringBuffer` in the background. So using the second method is not a problem if your Java version is 1.4 or above. But still, if you wanna concatinate strings is a loop, be careful.

## My suggestion:

Either use `StringBuffer` of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thankyou for the reminder. This thing was added after Java 1.4. Thankyou. Answer edited

Answer (score 3):

Not that i know of, but as already commented, its a single line piece of code that you could write yourself.

```
private String SurroundWord(String word, String surround){
    return surround + word + surround;   
}
```

Do note that this will return a New String object and not edit the original string.

Answer (score 3):

`StringUtils.wrap(str,wrapWith)` is what you are looking for.
If apache common utils is already a part of dependency, then you can use it. Otherwise as others already mentioned. It's better to add to your base. Not a big deal

https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java

Answer (score 2):

Create a new method:

```
public String surround(String s, String surr){
    return surr+s+surr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested the following and returns `%hello%`

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(surround("hello", "%")); 
}
public static String surround(String s, String sign) {
    return sign + s + sign;
}
```

Comment: Why post a late answer that's the same as 3 others?

Comment: it took me longer then the others, when i pressed post, there where no answers. Sorry.